# How to select the ids present in another table multiple columns?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have two tables TableA and TableB having structure as shown below:-

```
**TableA**

id | col_1  | col_2

1  |   A    |   B
2  |   C    |   D
3  |   E    |   F
4  |   G    |   H


**TableB**

id | TableA_first_col_id | TableA_second_col_id
1  |  1                  |   2
2  |  1                  |   3
```

Now, I want to check if TableA id is present in TableB  TableA_first_col_id column or in TableA_second_col_id column. 
Result should come to be

```
**TableA.id**
1
2
3
```

How can I write an optimised mysql query for this?

Comment: Please edit your question to format it properly. Look at some other questions, to see how formatting works.

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Ref: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I have added the expected output for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below ;

```
Select A.id
From TableA A
Where A.id in (select TableA_first_col_id From TableB) OR
      A.id in (select TableA_second_col_id from TableB)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table1 t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from table2 t2 
    where t1.id = t2.id and t1.program = t2.program
)
```

Comment: the expected result should check exists and not (not exists) but anyway i got the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Where exists command for larger entries in sub query is inefficient as it runs the sub query each time it checks with outer query row id.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from tableA where exists 
(   select id
    from tableB
    where tableA.id = tableB.first_col_id or tableA.id = tableB.second_col_id
)
```